# Pass array from JavaScript to Ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Is there any way we can pass values from javaScript to ejs without using `document.createElement`?

My View Engine is set as 'ejs' in express. I am making single page application and fetching data via vanilla JS. Upon request server is responding with array:

```
array = [{name:'anthony', age:'20'}, {name:'John', age:'25'}]
```

Now, I want to loop through this array and render the values in DOM without using `document.createElement`.

**I cannot render the page directly from server as** `res.render('index',{array})` **and do something like:**

```
<% array.forEach(data => {%>    
<h3><%= data.name %></h3>
 <%= data.age %>
 <% })%>
```

**I am sending data as** `res.json({array})` **and the data needs to be rendered from client side Vanilla Javascript.**

Comment: Ejs includes client-side rendering. It's even exampled on [their home page](https://ejs.co/) in the Get Started section under Browser Support.